# As400Text class vs MQC.MQGMO_CONVERT

Tags: java, ibm-mq, mq

Why some people prefer to use `As400Text` object to handle EBCDIC/ASCII conversion (Java code with IBM MQ jars) if we already have `MQC.MQGMO_CONVERT`  option to handle this?

My requirement is to convert ASCII->EBCDIC during the `PUT` operation which I am doing by  setting the character set to 37 and the write format to "STRING"  and using `MQC.MQGMO_CONVERT` option to automatically convert EBCDIC ->ASCII during the `GET` operation.

Is there any downfall of using convert option? Could anyone please let me know if this is not 100 percent safe option?

Answer (score 2):

Best practice is to write the MQ message in your local code page (where the CCSID and Encoding will normally be filled in automatically as the correct values) and to set the Format field. Then the getter will should use MQGMO_CONVERT to request the message in the CCSID and Encoding they need it in.

Get with Convert is safe, and will be correct so long as you provide the correct CCSID a and Encoding that describes the message, when you put it.

In the description of what you are doing in your question you convert from ASCII->EBCDIC before putting the message, and then getter is converting from EBCDIC->ASCII on the MQGET. This means you have paid for two data conversion operations, when you could have done none (or if two different ASCIIs, only one).